Макрос скрипт при отправке на печать в браузере, печать на разные принтеры
Ситуация, имеются 3 принтера
Один печатает А4, другие этикетки разных размеров.
Вся работа ведётся в браузере, оттуда же направляем на печать.
Окно печати запоминает последние значения, и если нужно напечатать чтото на другом принтере постоянно приходится менять все значения в диалоговом окне
(Размер бумаги, масштаб, отступы, кол-во копий и т.д.)
Собственно вопрос, есть ли какой-то скрипт, программа, макрос или ещё какое-то решение для данного вопроса?
Буду признательна за советы

Клиентский JS не имеет доступа к оборудованию пользователя...

@ksa, я тоже так думал, пока не увидел в функционале Chrome WebUSB API и "немного" офигел.
